# Use LINQ to join 2 objects for each of its properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have created 2 models to store the results of an sql query. Now I would like to join them for each of the week's... `(week1 = Record_id, week2 = Record_id)`
to get a new Object in which I would have all the data from the 1st model, as well as map data from the "Category" Model to it.

I created a new Model for it, but I am not sure how to write a linq query

First Model:

```
public class CustomData
{
    public string full_name { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public int week1 { get; set; }
    public int week2 { get; set; }
    public int week3 { get; set; }
}
```

Second Model:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Record_ID { get; set; }
    public int Color{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

New Model for end result:

```
public class WeekView
{
    public string full_name { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public Category week1 { get; set; }
    public Category week2 { get; set; }
    public Category week3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Example data please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
        List<CustomData> list = new List<CustomData>();
        list.Add(new CustomData() { full_name = "test", location = "test", week1 = 0, week2 = 1, week3 = 2 });
        list.Add(new CustomData() { full_name = "test2", location = "test2", week1 = 0, week2 = 12, week3 = 22 });
        List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
        categories.Add(new Category { Color = 0, Name = "testName", Record_ID = 0 });
        categories.Add(new Category { Color = 1, Name = "testName1", Record_ID = 1 });
        categories.Add(new Category { Color = 2, Name = "testName2", Record_ID = 2 });
        categories.Add(new Category { Color = 3, Name = "testName3", Record_ID = 12 });
        categories.Add(new Category { Color = 4, Name = "testName4", Record_ID = 22 });
        List<WeekView> results = new List<WeekView>();
        results.AddRange(list.Select(x=> 
              new WeekView() { full_name = x.full_name, 
                               location = x.location, 
                               week1 = categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Record_ID == x.week1), 
                               week2 = categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Record_ID == x.week2), 
                               week3 = categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Record_ID == x.week3)
                              }));
```

Comment: you could also do `categories.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Record_ID == x.week1)` it would be the same but more concise.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following:

```
var result = (from cd in CustomDatas
              join ca1 in Categories on cd.week1 equals ca.Record_ID into ca1r
              from ca1 in ca1r.DefaultIfEmpty()
              join ca2 in Categories on cd.week2 equals ca.Record_ID into ca2r
              from ca2 in ca2r.DefaultIfEmpty()
              join ca3 in Categories on cd.week3 equals ca.Record_ID into ca3r
              from ca3 in ca3r.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new {
                    full_name = cd.full_name,
                    location = cd.location,
                    week1 = ca1,
                    week2 = ca2,
                    week3 = ca3
              }
```

Comment: join ca1 in Categories - Categories is a type, which is not valid in the given context.

Comment: Where is Categories a type? The type is Category. I assumed for this example, that there is a List (or any other enumerable object) with a set of Category objects.